# How to get the current score of a document before calculating custom score

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a custom script in Java for scoring documents. I am looking to try and get the document's score prior to going into the custom scorer.

In mvel it seems that you can just do:
    "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value / pow(param1, param2)"

and _score will just give you the score. I don't see any effective way of getting the score with the Java API.

Note: I've tried doc().getScore() and that seems to always give a null pointer exception.

Bonus: How would I be able to get other document fields such as _boost or _index?

Comment: Are you using this script in the custom_score query?

Comment: yes. I'm using a multi_match custom score query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native script equivalent of "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value / pow(param1, param2)" would be:

```
@Override
public float runAsFloat() {
    return score() * doc().numeric("my_numeric_field").getFloatValue() / divider;
}
```

you can calculate `pow(param1, param2)` in the factory method since it doesn't change between `runAsFloat()` executions.

If `_index` field is [enabled](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/index-field.html), it can be accessed like this:

```
doc().field("_index").getStringValue()
```

I would recommend using query time boosting instead of index time boosting.